# Module request in nodejs don't stop pipe

Tags: node.js, request

I have used [dicer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/dicer) for parsing pipe by [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) but I don't know which command for stop pipe.

```
dicer.on('part', function(part) {
    var frameEncoded = '';
    part.setEncoding('base64');

    part.on('header', function(header) { });
    part.on('data', function(data) { frameEncoded += data; });
    part.on('end', function() { console.log(frameEncoded); });
});

  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://192.168.1.2/video.mjpeg/'
  }
  request(options).pipe(dicer)

 //only for test

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('stop request.pipe');
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://192.168.1.2/video.mjpeg/'
  }
  request(options).end() //<-- ?? which command?? This not work...
}, 5000);
```

The uri pointing to a stream of ipcamera and impossible grab event connection close of request because stream it's infinite.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get access to the underlying socket for the request is to listen for the `socket` event on the request object. Then it's just a matter of closing that socket. For example:

```
var req = request(options);
req.on('socket', function(sock) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('stop request.pipe');
    sock.end(); // or sock.destroy();
  }, 5000);
});
req.pipe(dicer);
```

Note though, the request may not have started yet when the `socket` event is emitted. The `socket` event basically lets you know that a socket has been assigned to be used for the request (this is especially useful when you are using an http Agent that has `maxSockets` set to some finite value so you may not necessarily get assigned a socket right away).

You could also try:

```
var req = request(options);
req.on('response', function(res) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('stop request.pipe');
    res.socket.end(); // or res.socket.destroy();
  }, 5000);
});
req.pipe(dicer);
```

Comment: In both cases I have received an error: 

`stop request.pipe
[Error: Unexpected end of multipart data]

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Part terminated early due to unexpected end of multipart data
    at /root/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:65:36
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)`

because dicer not finish part events. 
Exist one way for emit an event (ex: dicer.on('finish').... or req.on('close')....) for simulate stop streaming?

Comment: Ok, so what you would need to do is `req.unpipe(dicer);` before closing the socket. Then it'd probably be best to set up and use a new Dicer instance when/if you reconnect to the mjpeg stream.

Comment: Tnx mscdex for support but this way it's wrong too because, request module, not have method unpipe and the error that ret is: `TypeError: Object #<Request> has no method 'unpipe'`. Probably this module not compatible for us. Should be test with request by http module?

Comment: Ah, it seems there is an [issue for this](https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/874) already. You can probably just use the `http.get()`/`http.request()` built in to node though ...

Comment: `res.socket.destroy()` works in my case where I wanted to unpipe the request when a bad response code is received. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@mscdex's method works for me. Here is the code :-

```
   request("https://www.linkedin.com/afhdjalsdjhdks")
      .on("error", function (error) { process.stderr.write(error.code) })
      .on("response", function (resp) {
         if ((resp.statusCode !== 200) && (resp.statusCode !== 201)) {
            process.stderr.write(format("%s - %s", resp.statusCode, resp.statusMessage))
            resp.socket.destroy()
         }
      })
      // .pipe(StreamAll())
      .pipe(process.stdout)
```